# Why is my field `null` after injection? How do I inject my object?

Tags: android, dagger-2

> This is a [Canonical Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992/1837367) because there are a lot of misconceptions about object initialization with Dagger 2.
>
> *If your question was flagged as a duplicate* please read this post carefully and make sure to understand the difference between constructor injection and field injection.

I try to inject a `Context` into my presenter, but I get a NullPointerException when trying to use it.

```
class MyPresenter {

  @Inject Context context;

  private MyView view;

  @Inject
  MyPresenter(MyView view) {
    this.view = view;
  }
}
```

My module looks like this

```
@Module
class MyModule {

  @Provides
  MyPresenter provideMyPresenter(MyView view) {
    return new MyPresenter(view);
  }
}
```

I inject the presenter in my Activity here:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Inject MyPresenter presenter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    createMyActivityComponent().inject(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The above includes both **constructor and field injection**, but **neither done right**. The example would behave the same if we removed all the `@Inject` annotations from `MyPresenter` since we're not using any of them.

```
@Provides
MyPresenter provideMyPresenter(MyView view) {
  // no constructor injection, we create the object ourselves!
  return new MyPresenter(view);
}

// also no mention anywhere of component.inject(presenter)
// so the fields won't be injected either
```

Make sure to use *either* constructor injection *or* field injection. Mixing both will usually indicate an error in your setup or understanding.

- `@Inject` on a field is a marker for *field injection*
- `@Inject` on a constructor is a marker for *constructor injection*

This means your class should have *either of*

- a **single** `@Inject` on the constructor, or
- a `@Inject` on **all the fields to initialize**, but *none on the constructor*!

**Don't sprinkle `@Inject` everywhere and expect things to work!** Make sure to place the annotation where needed. Don't mix field and constructor injection!

**Constructor injection should be favored over field injection** as it creates an initialized and usable object. Field injection is to be used with Framework components where the Framework creates the objects. You have to manually call `component.inject(object)` for field injection to be performed, or any annotated fields *will be null* when you try to use them.

### Constructor Injection

As the name suggests you **put your dependencies** as parameters ***in the constructor***. The annotation on the constructor tells Dagger about the object and it can then *create the object for you* by calling it with all the required dependencies. Dagger will also inject any annotated fields or methods after creating the object, but plain constructor injection should usually be favored as it doesn't hide any dependencies.

Dagger creating the object also means there is **no need for a `@Provides` method in your module** that creates the object. All you need to do is add `@Inject` to the constructor and declare the dependencies.

```
class MyPresenter {

  private Context context;
  private MyView view;

  @Inject
  MyPresenter(MyView view, Context context) {
    this.view = view;
    this.context = context
  }
}
```

If you want to bind your implementation to an interface, there is still no need to create the object yourself.

```
@Module class MyModule {

  @Provides
  MyPresenter providePresenter(MyPresenterImpl presenter) {
    // Dagger creates the object, we return it as a binding for the interface!
    return presenter;
  }
}
```

And there is even a shorter (and more performant) version of the above use-case:

```
@Module interface MyModule {

  @Binds
  MyPresenter providePresenter(MyPresenterImpl presenter)
}
```

Constructor injection should be your default way of using Dagger. Make sure that you *don't call `new` yourself* or you misunderstood the concept.

### Field Injection

There are times when you *can't* use constructor injection, e.g. an Activity in Android gets created by the Framework and you shouldn't override the constructor. In this case we can use *field injection*.

To use field injection you annotate all the fields that you want initialized with `@Inject` and add a `void inject(MyActivity activity)` method to the component that should handle the injection.

```
@Component
interface MyComponent {
  void inject(MyActivity activity);
}
```

And somewhere in your code **you have to call `component.inject(myActivity)`** *or the fields will not be initialized.* e.g. in `onCreate(..)`

```
void onCreate(..) {
  // fields still null / uninitialized
  myComponent.inject(this);
  // fields are now injected!

  // ...
}
```

*Field injection is not transitive*. Just because you inject an Activity this does not mean that Dagger will also inject the fields of the presenter it injected. You have to inject every object manually, which is one reason why you should favor constructor injection.

There are tools that help mitigate the boilerplate of creating components and injecting your objects like `AndroidInjection.inject()` which will do this for you, but it still has to be done. Another example is [`AppInjector`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/8e77a8b90bec775bfdf9fa2244686f73265cdad2/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.kt) which adds various lifecycle listeners to inject your Activities and Fragments, but it will still call `AndroidInjection` which then creates your component and injects the object.

**Make sure that you inject the object before using it** and that there is no constructor annotated with `@Inject` to avoid confusion.

### What else?

There is also the lesser used [method injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39338870/1837367) and of course Dagger can't inject third party libraries, which you have to construct and provide in your modules.

Comment: You say that with constructor injection, annotated fields are ignored. But this is not quite true, right? If you annotate a field or method with `@Inject` while also having an `@Inject` annotated constructor, it will inject the field/method after initialization

Answer (score 0):

Remove **@Inject** from the **Context** and create a separate module for providing **Context**  dependency

```
@Module 
public class ContextModule {
    private final Context context;

    public ContextModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @MyAppScope
    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

then create your DaggerComponent. (I have created it in Application class and **this** refers to **ApplicationContext**

```
component =  DaggerDaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
            .MyModule()
            .build();
```

You can skip **.MyModule()** if you want because unlike **Context module** it has no external dependency.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this was intended as a canonical question and your answer should give good detail and explanation as to how to fix the issue at hand: the mix of constructor and field injection. E.g.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50266178/1837367) Following your answer alone the context would still be null without modifying the presenters constructor. You should probably also be using `@Component.Builder` with `@BindsInstance` to bind a context instead of a module, but how to bind a context to a component is not the focus of this canonical question.