# @inject interface not an implementation of that in dagger2 android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I want inject an inteface and dagger automatically inject my implemntation but i got error

```
public interface HouseInterface {
String sayHello();}
```

*the implementation of interface is below *

```
public class Stark implements  HouseInterface{
@Inject
public Stark(){}


@Override
public String sayHello() {
    return "stark";
}
```

}

*the house interface mosule*

```
@Module public class HouseModule {
@Provides
public HouseInterface getHouse(Stark stark){
    return stark;
}
}
```

*house component : *

```
@Component(modules = HouseModule.class) interface HouseComponent {
HouseInterface getHouse();
}
```

*War.class :*

```
 public class War {
@Inject
public War() {
}

//#1
//this not working
@Inject
HouseInterface houseInterface;

//this works
//#2
// @Inject
//Stark stark;

//#3
// this works//HouseComponent houseComponent = DaggerHouseComponent.builder().houseModule(new HouseModule()).build();
//HouseInterface houseInterface = houseComponent.getHouse();

public String getHouseName() {
    return houseInterface.sayHello();
}
```

}

*WarComponent class*

```
@Component
public interface WarComponent {
War getWar();
void inject(War war);
}
```

when i test code with below codes :

```
    @Test
public void printNameTest() {
    String expected = "stark";
    WarComponent component = DaggerWarComponent.create();
    War war= component.getWar();
    Assert.assertEquals(war.getHouseName(), expected);
}
```

if in War class we use #1 to inject, not working, but if use #2, or #3 that in above codes are commented injection doesnt work ,
any one has any  idea ?
because i dont want that war.class be dependent on Stark.class and i want that it just depends on HpuseInterface so i need the #1 working

Comment: For field injection you have to provide a method that takes `war` as a parameter in the corresponding `component` , so that `dagger` will understand that you want to inject fields of the `war` class .

Comment: @AbuYousuf
in HouseComponent like below ?
@Component(modules = HouseModule.class)
interface HouseComponent {
    void getHouse(War war);
}
this doesnt work

Comment: What error you are getting? Provide your `WarComponent` code

Comment: First of all, you're [mixing field with constructor injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50270375/1837367) which is why #2 should compile but not work. Other than that your WarComponent most likely knows nothing about HouseComponent, which is why it can't bind Stark as a House. Either make war a subcomponent or add a component dependency on house.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak
#2 works, #1 doesnt work
and #2 depends war class to stark class,
i want make #1 working to to independent war.class from stark.class or any house implementation

Comment: #2 will be null, as pointed out in the linked question, unless you have some more code for field injection that you didn't share. It should compile but not "work". It's hard to say why #1 won't work, since you did not share `WarComponent` with us. I guess that your WarComponent knows nothing about HouseComponent, which is why it can't bind Stark as a House. So either make war a subcomponent or add a component dependency on house.

Comment: sorry @DavidMedenjak i thought that i shared war component,
i edit my post

Component
public interface WarComponent {
    War getWar();
    void inject(War war);
}

Comment: As I assumed, WarComponent knows nothing about HouseComponent, which is why it can't bind Stark as a House. So either make WarComponent a subcomponent or add a component dependency on HouseComponent.

Comment: `WarComponent` doesn't know `HouseModule` so of course you can't `HouseInterface` from it