# Dagger2 Component inject for multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

This seems very basic question for `Dagger2` users . I have recently started exploring it with `RetroFit`. I have followed some tutorials and came up with the code below(some of it).

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ApiModule.class})
     public interface ApiComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity context);
     }


    public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private ApiComponent mApiComponent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .apiModule(new ApiModule("https://rect.otp/demos/"))
                .build();
    }
    public ApiComponent getNetComponent() {
        return mApiComponent;
    }
   }
```

And MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;
ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
    ApiCall api = retrofit.create(ApiCall.class);
}
}
```

**Questions**
1. When i change `void inject(MainActivity context);` to `void inject(Context context);` i am getting a `NullPointerException` on `retrofit` in `MainActivity`.Why?

2. When use `void inject(MainActivity context);` its working fine. Why ?
3. If i need to inject `RetroFit` in Multiple classes what should be the approach. Creating `inject()` for each class is not seems the solution.

I am a newbie to dependency Injections. So Can i have some guidence on it . What will be the proper approach to use it in multiple classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare `void inject(Context context)` Dagger will generate code to inject `Context`. Since `Context` does not declare any `@Inject` annotated fields it will end up injecting nothing. This is why your `retrofit` is `null` after the injection.

When you declare `void inject(MainActivity context)` it will generate code to inject `MainActivity` that will also set your `retrofit`, thus it will be initialized.

Dagger will inject parent fields, but not childrens. The class that you declare is the one that the code will be generated for.

Your default way to inject objects should be *Constructor Injection* where you don't have to manually declare methods or inject the objects. e.g. see [this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270376/1837367).

Comment: Thx for answer David . That's a great one . So what i understood that i have to create multiple inject methods if i need a field injection in multiple Activities and Fragments ? Am i wrong here ?

Comment: Its a Coincident My last 4 questions are only answered by the developers from Austria in recent 3 days. Thx