# Kotlin lateinit not working with @Inject annotation

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I am new to dagger 2 and kotlin both. Getting lateinit property not initialized.

I have a module which have few @Provides methods but one of the class not able to create object which used @Inject and lateinit.

Login service takes **"LoginAPI"** as parameter and works fine but as i want all my login related API's to use the same service. There is one more API related **"LoginWithOrgAPI"**.

Now my need is to get any API object when needed in the **LoginService** class. So i tries using lateinit with @Inject as show in LoginService class but its not working.

```
@Module(includes = [(NetworkingModule::class)])

class LoginModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginApi(retrofit: Retrofit): LoginApi =
            retrofit.create(LoginApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginWithOrgApi(retrofit: Retrofit): LoginWithOrgApi =
            retrofit.create(LoginWithOrgApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginService(api: LoginApi): LoginService =
            LoginService(api)

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginInteractor(apiService: LoginService): LoginInteractor =
            LoginInteractor(apiService)
}
```

// adding LoginService class

```
class LoginService(val loginAPI: LoginApi) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var loginWithOrgApi: LoginWithOrgApi


    fun loginAPIService(user: String, password: String?, extension: String, otp: String?,
                       hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData> {
        password?.let {

            return loginAPI.getLogin(user, it, extension, null, hardwareId)
        }?: run {
            return loginAPI.getLogin(user, null, extension, otp, hardwareId)
        }
    }

    fun loginWithOrg(user: String, password: String?, extension: String, otp: String?,
                     userId: String, hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData>{
        password?.let {

            return loginWithOrgApi.getLogin(user, it, extension, null, userId, hardwareId)
        }?: run {
            return loginWithOrgApi.getLogin(user, null, extension, otp, userId, hardwareId)
        }
    }
}
```

// component

```
@Component(modules = [(LoginModule::class)])

    interface LoginComponent {

           fun loginInteractor(): LoginInteractor

    }
```

// api interface

```
interface LoginWithOrgApi {

    @POST("access/v1/login/")
      @FormUrlEncoded
      fun getLogin(@Field("user") user: String,
                   @Field("password") password: String?,
                   @Field("mobile_extension") extension: String,
                   @Field("otp") otp: String?,
                   @Field("user_id") userId: String,
                   @Field("hardware_id") hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData>

}
```

Getting the crash saying **"lateinit"** property not initialized when trying to call method "loginWithOrg"

My understanding is that once define and provided through module, i can get the object through @Inject in the dependency graph but something is missing here.

// my objective for  LoginService class

```
class LoginService() {

    @Inject
    var loginWithOrgApi: LoginWithOrgApi 


@Inject
        var loginApi: LoginApi



    fun loginAPIService(user: String, password: String?, extension: String, otp: String?,
                       hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData> {
        password?.let {

            return loginAPI.getLogin(user, it, extension, null, hardwareId)
        }?: run {
            return loginAPI.getLogin(user, null, extension, otp, hardwareId)
        }
    }

    fun loginWithOrg(user: String, password: String?, extension: String, otp: String?,
                     userId: String, hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData>{
        password?.let {

            return loginWithOrgApi.getLogin(user, it, extension, null, userId, hardwareId)
        }?: run {
            return loginWithOrgApi.getLogin(user, null, extension, otp, userId, hardwareId)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you creating the object (`LoginService(api)`), but I don't see you injecting it&mdash;hence the fields won't be set. You should have a look at [constructor injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270376/1837367) which would reduce the boilerplate and fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There are two API's in the module class, **LoginAPI** and **LoginWithOrgAPI**.  LoginAPI is passed in the service class inside constructor and is working fine but the other one i'm trying to get it through @Inject which i want to use in the second function written. That particular one is not working.

Comment: do you mean i should remove the constructor parameter and try to inject both the API's through @Inject annotation?

Comment: Hope you have mentioned your class(In which you want to inject the object) in the component interface of the dagger.

Comment: Please paste all code

Comment: added more code, which shows all the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are mixing two independent things: member injection via `void inject(MyClass myClass);` and constructor injection.

In fact, you even have a separate field that "ought to be member-injected", even though you could technically receive that as a constructor param?

> ```
> class LoginService(val loginAPI: LoginApi) { // <-- constructor param + field
>
>     @Inject
>     lateinit var loginWithOrgApi: LoginWithOrgApi // <-- why is this a lateinit member injected field? 
>     // this could also be constructor param
> ```

---

So it should be as follows.

```
@Module(includes = [(NetworkingModule::class)])

class LoginModule {

    @Provides
    fun loginApi(retrofit: Retrofit): LoginApi =
            retrofit.create(LoginApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun loginWithOrgApi(retrofit: Retrofit): LoginWithOrgApi =
            retrofit.create(LoginWithOrgApi::class.java)

    //@Provides
    //fun provideLoginService(api: LoginApi): LoginService =
    //        LoginService(api)

    //@Provides
    //fun provideLoginInteractor(apiService: LoginService): LoginInteractor =
    //        LoginInteractor(apiService)
}
```

and

```
class LoginService @Inject constructor(
    val loginAPI: LoginApi, 
    val loginWithOrgApi: LoginWithOrgApi
) {
    fun loginAPIService(user: String, password: String?, extension: String, otp: String?,
                       hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData> {
        password?.let { password ->
            return loginAPI.getLogin(user, password, extension, null, hardwareId)
        }?: run {
            return loginAPI.getLogin(user, null, extension, otp, hardwareId)
        }
    }

    fun loginWithOrg(user: String, password: String?, extension: String, otp: String?,
                     userId: String, hardwareId: String): Single<LoginAPIResponseData>{
        password?.let { password ->
            return loginWithOrgApi.getLogin(user, password, extension, null, userId, hardwareId)
        }?: run {
            return loginWithOrgApi.getLogin(user, null, extension, otp, userId, hardwareId)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class LoginInteractor @Inject constructor(
    val apiService: LoginService
) {
    ...
}
```

You own those classes, so there is no reason to use `@field:Inject lateinit var` + `void inject(MyClass myClass);` here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try this and will let you know about the result. Actually as there are two login API's in my service class which i need depending on the situation. As i was planning my code my objective was to remove constructor param and later instantiate the API which is really required through **lazy** initialization but actually didn't knew how to go about it.

Comment: Another question just in case i have 5-10 API's in a module and want to have single service class only, Then how to go about it. Having constructor params won't suit. Editted my question with the objective as well.

Comment: It worked, thanks. How mixing both constructor injection and field injection led to the crash?  In theory it was looking fine to me.

Comment: You didn't ever invoke `component.inject(injectionTarget)` and you also didn't have a `@Inject constructor` therefore the class was never injected. You might also want to consider not making a new interface per each REST API call, you only need that if you have different baseUrl or different okClient.

Comment: If you want to lazy-inject something, then just get `@Inject constructor(val lazyService: dagger.Lazy<LoginWithOrgApi>...)`